# Calling c++ routines in Matlab

Tags: c++, matlab, mex

I've got a long code in C++ and I want to call it from MATLAB.

I read that, using MEX-files, calling large pre-existing C/C++ and Fortran routines from MATLAB without rewriting them as MATLAB functions is possible.

However, MEX files are cumbersome and apparently one should change the whole code. Furthermore, I have problems in calling the C/C++ compiler from MATLAB's command line. In particular, MATLAB asks

```
Select a compiler: 
[1] Lcc-win32 C 2.4.1 in D:\PROGRA~1\MATLAB\R2013a\sys\lcc
[2] Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 in D:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0
```

but my code is written in Borland c++ but MATLAB could not recognize Borland as a compiler.

Is there any way, simpler than what I'm currently doing, to integrate C/C++ codes in MATLAB by MEX-files?

Comment: If you decide to use Visual Studio, I would suggest to follow the procedure in [Compiling mex files with Visual Studio](http://www.orangeowlsolutions.com/archives/490). You will find also a template Visual Studio project which will simplify your integration of C/C++ code into Matlab.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As mentioned by user2485710, you should use the MEX interface to call your existing C++ code. MEX interface is basically a wrapper around your existing C++ code.

For example, if your called is call *add.c*, which adds two numbers, you will not be able to call it directly in MATLAB. Your wrapper should look like this,

```
#include "mex.h"
void mexFunction( int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[],
              int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[]) { // Standard gateway function
    double *a = mxGetPr(prhs[0]);
    double *b = mxGetPr(prhs[1]);
    double c = add(a,b);
    mxSetPr(plhs[0], &c);
}
```

This is a illustrative example, you might have to read the documentation for the each of the functions I have used. You need not worry about the compiler. Most C++ programs work in all compilers. Choose one of the compilers in your list and work with it. There are some limitations, but I do not know of anyone who hit this usecase.

Answer (score 2):

reading from [here](http://www.mathworks.com/support/compilers/interface.html) , it's clear that Matlab can be interfaced with C or Fortran; now how do you go from C++ to C ? You use `extern "C"` .

Read [here](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/cpp-objs-passed-to-c.html) for a quick intro on the subject, but basically it's all you have to do, put an `extern` to expose C interfaces for your C++ functions so both the linker and the compiler know how to correctly build a C interface.

The FAQ also discuss [some limitations](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/get-cpp-data-members-from-c.html) of this solution because of the different features offered by C++ and C.

Comment: MEX-files can be written in C++ as well, although you can't directly return C++ objects to MATLAB (there are techniques to do so by keeping them around between invocations). Data passed between the two should use the opaque type `mxArray` and the associated MEX API functions.

Comment: @Amro I would never do that because `extern "C"` is the only trustable way for me to translate C++ to C and viceversa, it's a mechanism that comes free with your compiler and linker and if it fails it can only be your fault. I'm not incline to translate C++ code to C just using an header or a library.

Comment: The code in "mex.h" and all other MATLAB headers are already exporting their functions with C linkage if being compiled under a C++ compiler (the usual `#ifdef __cplusplus` macros). I've never ran into any trouble with that..

Comment: Here is what I had in mind when I said you can manipulate C++ objects from MATLAB: http://www.ee.columbia.edu/~mim/meap/paMat/mexhandle/ , there are other techniques as well (place objects in a global static std::map and return a corresponding id number to MATLAB, etc..)

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to making a real matlab interface using MEX-files, you could also simply call your C++ program via [system calls](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/ref/system.html). You'd have to write the data it needs to files first, which is inefficient, but probably better than writing a true interface if you are not planning to use it often.

Comment: another possibility is [FFI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_function_interface) to interface with the library using the [loadlibrary](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/loadlibrary.html) mechanism, although I think writing a MEX-wrapper is more robust